# How to sanitize variables passed down from a top Makefile?

Tags: makefile, syntax, gnu-make, sanitization

I am looking for guidance here as I recently encountered an issue when it came to comparisons using `ifeq` on variables that originated from a top-level Makefile I have no control over, and it made me wonder if there is a way to sanitize or standardize variables so that I can consistently use the same type of comparison going forward.

This is the problem I ran into, notice the use of `"` around values.

```
my_target:
ifeq ($(strip $(TOP_VAR_1)), "VALUE")
    #this comparison yields true
endif

ifeq ($(strip $(TOP_VAR_2)), VALUE)
    #this comparison yields true
endif
```

I was able to get these comparisons to work by trial and error based on [GNU's conditional syntax guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html), but this took me a great amount of time to do so.

Previous attempts include playing around with `strip` and quotation marks on variables and values, yet those still yielded a false equality.

e.g.

```
my_target:
ifeq ($(strip $(TOP_VAR_1)), VALUE)
    #this comparison yields false
endif

ifeq ($(strip $(TOP_VAR_2)), "VALUE")
    #this comparison yields false
endif
```

Comment: You will have to restrict or at least describe which "sanitization" (sp?) you have in mind - spaces, " and ', dots, slashes etc. If the problem is only dealing with `"` then a simple `TOP_VAR := $(subst ",,$(TOP_VAR))` to canonicalize their format would be enough.

Comment: @Vroomfondel I did not envision some specific sanitization given printing out values did not show any characters or white spaces out of place (e.g. no `"VALUE" or `VALUE ``) so I didn't understand what was going on that caused the comparison to fail, thus me attempting to get the values to a "standard" format

Comment: Well, we are still in exact-string-compare land with `make`, so for two strings to compare equal, you will need to be *totally specific* otherwise you won't be able to accomodate to `make`s wish of character-by-character equality. I take it that you would be ok with all funny quote characters and spaces removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very unclear what exactly your question is.  And, since you didn't show us what the actual values of the `TOP_VAR_1` or `TOP_VAR_2` variables are, we can't really provide any guidance.

I will say two things: first if you use the `ifeq (...)` form, then GNU  make completely ignores quotes (or rather, treats them as any other character and not special in any way).  And second, the *only* thing the `strip` function does is remove extra whitespace.  It doesn't do anything with quotes.

So in your examples:

```
ifeq ($(strip $(TOP_VAR_1)), "VALUE")
```

This will be true if the value of the `TOP_VAR_1` variable is the string `"VALUE"` (**including the quotes!!**), possibly with leading or trailing whitespace (as in, it would match  `"VALUE"`  but it would NOT match `"  VALUE  "` or `VALUE` etc.)

```
ifeq ($(strip $(TOP_VAR_2)), VALUE)
```

This matches if `TOP_VAR_2` is the string `VALUE` (without quotes!) possibly with leading or trailing whitespace (as in, it would match  `VALUE`  but it would NOT match `"VALUE"` etc.)

If you want to see what these variables contain the simplest way is using the `info` function:

```
$(info TOP_VAR_2='$(TOP_VAR_2)')
```

Whatever is inside the `''` in the output is the string that `ifeq` will operate on.  You can of course also add the `strip` function to see how that changes things.

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment from above, a sanitizing function applied to variable contents would look like this:

```
sanitize-var = $(subst ',,$(subst `,,$(subst ",,$(strip $1))))

TOP_VAR_1_san := $(call sanitize-var,$(TOP_VAR_1))
TOP_VAR_2_san := $(call sanitize-var,$(TOP_VAR_2))

ifeq ($(TOP_VAR_1_san),FOO bar)
....
```

Comment: This function is very handy and is really well complemented by @MadScientis's explanation. It turned out you we're right and "hidden" quotations were contained in the top variable that were escaped by `echo`